# Can I use Coinhive to mine Monero without problems with Google Safebrowsing?

Tags: mining, coin-hive

I have several popular freeware applications and also some popular web apps and I would like to monetize them. So I'm thinking about using Coinhive Captcha on my website and let visitors of my website mine (not secretly) Monero for me. Do you think I can do that without getting problems with Google Safebrowsing?

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome as far as I'm aware doesn't block the coinhive miner that asks for your permission, so unless you're having an issue already I think you'll be fine.